# How to set toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener only for current fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

Started new project from navigation drawer activity template. By default, all drawer menu items are at the same navigation level. All fragments display hamburger menu button, that shows drawer.

[image]

I need to keep all items in drawer, but place Home as top level item and others as it's children like this:

[image]

Tried to overwrite `toolbar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {  }` in Gallery fragment, but it also affects Home fragment and I didn't find how to restore default behavior.

How can I set Home as navigation parent for others or how to set navigation click listener to only one fragment?

Comment: Keep a tag for every fragment and check where you want to click event manage with tags

Answer (score -1):

For example  you have set tag for every fragment to trace when you start new fragment and now check with Home and set click event..

```
 Fragment home = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("home");
```